# Mysql - find conversation only being held by two users

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having

I have a table called participants with the following fields:

- id
- user_id
- conversation_id

The background is that there are conversations with at least two or more participants. I want to find a conversation that has only been held by two specified users, with no other users in the conversation.

I have come up with the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM participants
WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_id = 2
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Given this content

[image: participant table image]

you can see that the users 1 and 2 share a conversation with user 3 (conversation 1), but also have one conversation alone (conversation 2).

The query above in fact returns the right conversation_id (i.e. 2) - but I am not sure whether the query is correct. When I say `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`it returns conversation 1, and I am not sure why. Intuitively I used having count - and it seems to work if set to 1 - but I am not sure what it does in this context.

Is the query correct? If so, why? If not, what do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your query will not work since the `where` clause filters out the user_ids. Use

```
SELECT * FROM participants
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING sum(user_id not in (1,2)) = 0
```

`user_id not in (1,2)` returns `1` if a `user_id` other than `1,2` are in a conversation and `0` otherwise. So using `SUM` you can add up all that cases. If none are found then the sum is `0`.

Comment: It works when I put 1,3 in the columns, thank you! Can you elaborate how that works with the sum? I am not sure I understand it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Piece it together, from the inner-most expression, outward.  `user_id not in (1, 2)` - that expression will return 1 for any rows where the `user_id` is not 1 or 2.  Then, `SUM()` returns the sum of all its arguments.  The final effect of the `HAVING` clause is to remove all the conversations where the only participants are not `user_id 1` and `user_id 2`.

Comment: @juergend you said "user_id not in (1,2) returns 1 if no user_id other than 1,2 are in a conversation and 0 otherwise" - shouldn't it be the other way round, since we are checking for 0 and that returns the right conversation?

Answer (score 0):

```
select conversation_id
from participants
where user_id in (1,2)
group by conversation_id
having count(user_id) = 2
```

Return two users conversation_id