# Rails & Mysql - Optimize and rephrase query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788433/mysql-find-conversation-only-being-held-by-two-users/13788449#13788449) to a previous question of mine and [this article](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/sql-having-clause-in-rails-activerecord) I found a way to rephrase this query:

```
SELECT * FROM participants
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING sum(user_id not in (1,3)) = 0
```

to this Rails style query:

```
Participant.find(:all, group: "conversation_id HAVING sum(user_id not in (1,3)) = 0")
```

I am new to Rails, but it seems to me that this is old syntax - what bothers me the most is that I use a lot of sql in there, instead of doing it all in Rails syntax.

How can I rephrase the query above even more so that it is only written in Rails syntax, possibly without any need for quotation marks? I need to make sure that this will run with different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails 3 way would be:

```
Participant.group("conversation_id").having("sum(user_id not in (1,3)) = 0")
```

You won't be able to do away with strings in the having clause. What's your concern with strings? The query above should be fairly portable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If you say this has maximum portability, then it's what I need. I am using a mysql database in development and testing and pqsql in production - that's why I'm concerned with compatibility.

Comment: Any reason why you're using mysql for development? Nothing against it, just wondering why you'd have two different DBs. If you're on a Mac you should check out http://postgresapp.com. It's perfect for a dev env.

Comment: I set it up before I knew Heroku uses postgresql ;-) Is it easy to switch locally? Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's easy if you don't care about the dev data. I throw mine away regularly and import from production backups. I'd suggest moving to avoid any problems when deploying to production.

Comment: I see - I will consider that. Thanks!