# Conversations SQL Structure (Group chat)

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

In the past week I have been trying to come up with the best structure for a conversations chat, after doing a lot of searching, and trying to find better answers. The current structure I have so far, looks like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It must be possible to:

- Have up to (n) participants in a group. (Let's say n = 5)
- Check if a conversation already exists between the participants (this has been bothering me..)
- Show the latest conversations, sorted by unread and timestamp of last message (should work)

**Show the latest conversations (sort by unread and timestamp)**

```
SELECT * FROM chat_participants WHERE pageId = ? AND isMuted=0 ORDER BY isRead DESC, lastmod DESC
```

**Check if a conversation already exists between participants**

The **client user** will be able to send a new message to a specific **end user**, or start a new group chat with **up to 5 participants**. Instead of starting a new conversation each time, I would like to check whether or not the conversation exists already, to append the message there instead. I hope it makes sense. This specific feature has been bothering me pretty much all the time, when I have been trying to come up with a good structure. Does anyone have an idea to solve this "peacefully" with this structure, or do you have better ideas? Thanks :)

I tried things like checking if the **page id's** existed in the **chat_participants** with the same chat id, but this brings up its own disadvantages. This is something I tried, but obviously doesn't work as intended, as it returns (x) records, which could be entirely different chatId values.

```
SELECT * FROM chat_participants WHERE pageId IN(<id1>,<id2>)
```

I appreciate your input on this. Have a great day ahead! :)

**Edit (Answer to @Gordon Linoff)**
Example of recipients table:
[image]

I used your code such as this: (This one works)

```
SELECT cp.chatId FROM chatParticipants cp GROUP BY cp.chatId HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(pageId ORDER BY pageId) IN('p1,p2')
```

But when I try to check another conversation, with other recipients, such as below, it does not.

```
SELECT cp.chatId FROM chatParticipants cp GROUP BY cp.chatId HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(pageId ORDER BY pageId) IN('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480,123')
```

Also, why does it only seem to work when the values are wrapped within the same quotation marks? E.g if this is used, nothing is returned as well `IN ('p1', 'p2')`

**Edit 2**

So I combined some of the suggested answers here, and came up with this query.

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants GROUP BY chatId HAVING SUM(pageId NOT IN('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480','123')) = 0
```

It works, sort of, the only issue I have found so far with this above query, is that something like the below query, still returns a chatId value. (**Even though (144) does not exist in chatParticipants)**

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants GROUP BY chatId HAVING SUM(pageId NOT IN('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480','144','123')) = 0
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788433/mysql-find-conversation-only-being-held-by-two-users

Comment: @Progman Thank you, will have a look at this as well.

Comment: @Progman Please have a look at (Edit 2). Do you have any idea why it works fine with 2 inputs, but with 3 (where 1 is not existing) it still returns chat id, which is not the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a MCVE to make it easier for everyone to help, see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Provide sample data and the query you run against them, show the output you get and the output you should actually get instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a `chatId` exists for a specific group of participants then one method is aggregation.  For instance, to find chats where exactly 1, 2, and 3 participate:

```
select cp.chatid
from chat_participants cp
group by cp.chatid
having group_concat(pageid order by pageid)= '1,2,3';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining the meaning of the "cp" variable? Have a great day! :)

Comment: Hey, your solution only seems to work when there's two records? Whenever I try to add a new chat, and recipients, and use the same code, with different page id's it returns nothing.

Comment: @Anders . . . `cp` is a table aliases.  As for adding more pages, you need to be sure they are in the correct order, so the `group_concat()` matches.

Comment: Ordering by what? The page id, chat id? Thanks.

Comment: @Anders . . . `'1,2,3'` are `page_id`s in your query.  This is the comparison string and it needs to be in order.

Comment: The user experience enables them to select pages. Isn't there another way, to only get records with specific page id's, that shares the same chatId value in a cleaner way?